# How to return a value, but keep executing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple tree class and I need to be able to iterate over the leaf nodes only.

I add the data to my tree as follows:

```
p = ParamTree()
p.add('system.screen.timeout')
p.add('system.screen.lock.enabled')
p.add('system.screen.lock.code')
```

and I want to be able to get `timeout`, `enabled` and `code` in sequence.

If I write a function to print the values, it works as expected:

```
def print_nodes(tree):
    for node in tree.nodes:
        if node.has_children():
            print_nodes(node)
        else:
            print(node)
```

Output:

```
>>> print_nodes(p)
timeout
enabled
code
```

How would I go about implementing a generator that does the same thing? I tried replacing `print()` with `yield`, but it doesn't work.

```
def yield_nodes(tree):
    for node in tree.nodes:
        if node.has_children():
            yield_nodes(node)
        else:
            yield node
```

Output:

```
>>> g = yield_nodes(p)
>>> for n in g:
...   print(n)
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume your `yield_nodes` generator to be written as follows:

```
def yield_nodes(tree):
    for node in tree.nodes:
        if node.has_children():
            yield_nodes(node)
        else:
            yield node
```

As you might notice, calling `yield_nodes` returns a generator (that you could iterate over), but you are not actually doing anything with it. My proposed solution would be the following:

```
def yield_nodes(tree):
    for node in tree.nodes:
        if node.has_children():
            yield from yield_nodes(node)
        else:
            yield node
```